# Correct way to drive Main Loop in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, architecture

I'm writing a game that currently runs in both Windows and Mac OS X. My main game loop looks like this:

```
while(running)
{
    ProcessOSMessages(); // Using Peek/Translate message in Win32
                         // and nextEventMatchingMask in Cocoa
    GameUpdate();
    GameRender();
}
```

Thats obviously simplified a bit, but thats the gist of it. In Windows where I have full control over the application, it works great. Unfortunately Apple has their own way of doing things in Cocoa apps.

When I first tried to implement my main loop in Cocoa, I couldn't figure out where to put it so I created my own `NSApplication` per [this post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/demystifying-nsapplication-by.html). I threw my `GameFrame()` right in my `run` function and everything worked correctly.

However, I don't feel like its the "right" way to do it. I would like to play nicely within Apple's ecosystem rather than trying to hack a solution that works.

[This article](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1385/_index.html) from apple describes the old way to do it, with an `NSTimer`, and the "new" way to do it using `CVDisplayLink`. I've hooked up the `CVDisplayLink` version, but it just feels....odd. I don't like the idea of my game being driven by the display rather than the other way around.

Are my only two options to use a `CVDisplayLink` or overwrite my own `NSApplication`? Neither one of those solutions feels quite right.

Answer (score 2):

I am curious to see if anyone who has actually done this cares to weigh in, but here is my understanding:

Apple pushes the `CVDisplayLink` solution over doing a loop on the main thread that uses `-nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:` because, I think, it provides better responsiveness for UI controls. This may not be relevant for full-screen games. (Note: You don't need to replace `NSApplication` to use that form of game loop.) I *think* the main potential issue with using `CVDisplayLink` is that it will only run one frame in advance and it does this determination early, which is even stronger than vertical sync. On the plus side, it might improve latency.

Other solutions include decoupling rendering from game logic and running game logic periodically on the main thread and rendering on the `CVDisplayLink` thread. I would probably only recommend this, however, if you run into issues with the game-driven-by-display paradigm.

Comment: The `CVDisplayLink` method currently works for me with no issues, it just feels...odd. I know that's not the best reason to not use it, I'm just curious if there's a better/more intuitive solution. Is this really what commercial game studios use?

Comment: I would guess most commercial games ignore Apple's recommendation and do a loop on the main thread, or else not use the Cocoa frameworks directly at all. On the other hand I think most iPhone games use `CADisplayLink`, which is the equivalent. I'd also point out that if you use vsync, your game is already (indirectly) being driven by the display.

Comment: Ironically, porting to the iPhone is what provided this inspiration to find the "right" way to do it. The iPhone version is indeed driven by the display, which doesn't feel quite as weird because it makes more sense there, IMO. Vsync is an option in my game, but during development I keep it off so I can do real performance measurements.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to make your own NSApplication based class or use CVDisplayLink to get around the fact that an app's runloop is hidden from you in Cocoa.

You could just create a thread and have your run loop in there instead.

For what it's worth though, I just use CVDisplayLink.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The use of NSTimer to control a game loop is not stable.  See comment below, and reference CVDisplayLink.

---

I'm sticking something up here to revive this question...mainly out of portability.  I found from studying the OLC Pixel Game Engine, that it works with a do{}while loop and std::chrono to check the timing of the frame to calculate fElapsed Time.  Below is some code I wrote to do the same thing.  It also adds a makeup portion, to govern the framerate from shooting above a certain value, in this case, 60 FPS.

c++ code

```
int maxSpeedMicros = 16700;
float fTimingBelt; //used to calculate fElapsedTime for internal calls.
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point timingBelt[2];
bool engineRunning = false; //always have it true, until the engine stops.
bool isPaused = false;

do {
    timingBelt[1] = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    fTimingBelt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(timingBelt[1] - timingBelt[0]).count() * 0.000001;
    if (isPaused) {
        do {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            timingBelt[1] = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        } while (isPaused);
    }
    timingBelt[0] = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    // do updating stuff here.
    
    timingBelt[1] = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    int frameMakeup = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(timingBelt[1] - timingBelt[0]).count();
    if (frameMakeup < maxSpeedMicros) {
        int micros = maxSpeedMicros - frameMakeup;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::microseconds(micros));
    }
} while (engineRunning);
```

However, that code was in direct conflict with Cocoa's event driven model.
[Custom main application loop in cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768645/custom-main-application-loop-in-cocoa/38768954?noredirect=1#comment64910793_38768954)
So as a bandaid, I commented out the whole loop, and created a new method that runs one iteration of the loop.  I then implemented this in my AppDelegate:

Objective C Code

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    engine->resetTimer();
    
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.016666666667 target:self selector:@selector(engineLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(void) engineLoop { //Let's handle this by the engine object.  That's too complicated!
    engine->updateState();
    [glView update]; //Since the engine is doing all of its drawing to a GLView
    [[glView openGLContext] flushBuffer];
}
```

Still to do is adjust the tolerance of the timer object.  Apple Developer documentation states that if a timer object misses the next window, it will wait for the next frame time.  However, a tolerance allows it to shift the timing of future events to make smoother framerate transitions and better use of CPU power.

So at this point I am open to suggestions and input about what others have done to make more portable code.  I am planning on a boolean argument in the constructor of the engine named "eventDriven" and if false, will start its own game loop thread, then split out the top event loop to call an "engineUpdate" method that handles all of the code that can be event driven. Then in the case of building on an event driven system, the delegate can just construct the engine with a engineUpdate = TRUE and have their events drive the gameUpdate.

Has anyone done this? and if so, how does it perform cross platform?

Comment: Late reply - but I wanted to address why this approach _should not_ be used. It's not compatible with variable frame rate (which CVDisplayLink is) and it doesn't synchronize with frame timings so it can cause tearing.

Any drawing on a timer should happen within a CVDisplayLink. Never NSTimer.

Comment: Thanks for adding this comment!  I updated the top of my post to highlight your comment.  I completely forgot I wrote this.